# SQLite3 database rotation

Tags: sqlite

I have a large amount of data and I want to automatically rotate it after it reaches a certain number of records. How can I add this functionality in sqlite3?

Comment: "add [to] sqlite" as in modify sqlite itself or ..? As it is now, there is *not enough context*.

Comment: No, not modify it. I meant how I can achieve it in SQLite3?